# how to return a value from a method inside another method php

Tags: php, pdo

i got two methods.one method is to insert data and the other one is to get the id of the inserted data. i tried several test but it doesn't give any return value.is it possible to pass a return value from another method?

```
public function insertRegistrantInfo($fname, $lname) {


    $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `registrants_info` (`first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES (?,?)");

    $query->bindValue(1, $fname);
    $query->bindValue(2, $lname);


    try {

        $row = $query->execute();
        //$log = $this->getSessionID($email);       
        return $this->getSessionID($email);     

        #mail function can be added here

        }catch(PDOException $e) {

        die($e->getMessage());

    }
}

public function getSessionID($email) {
    try {
    //global $bcrypt;

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `registrants_info` WHERE `email` = ?");

    $query->bindValue(1, $email);



        $query->execute();
        $data1 = $query->fetch();

        $id  = $data1['id'];
        //echo $id;
        return $id;

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
        }
}
```

and the returning page is here:

```
if($data = $admin->insertRegistrantInfo($fname, $lname) == true) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION['id'] =  $data;

            //print_r($_SESSION);
    header('location: registry.php');
    exit();

}
```

Comment: Ouch... why are you doing this to yourself? Right after your insert you can just do $query->getLastInsertId(); In your fashion you are making a seperate database call for the information that is already being given to you.

Comment: $row = $query->execute(); if (!$row) { // you have an error } $insertId = $query->getLastInsertId();

Comment: Where does `$email` come from?

Comment: Wait, I was about to answer this but now I'm even more confused. You are only inserting firstname and lastname... so how can you query based on the email? It's not in the record.

Comment: exactly @Rottingham i just added that function and remove the other method. but when it returns it give me the id 1 which is supposed to be 1222 from my database, am i missing a syntax on the returning page?

Comment: @user3052545 is the ID field set to auto-increment?

Comment: @user3052545 The correct method is `lastInsertId()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the lastInsertID() method on your query object rather than a second query

```
public function insertRegistrantInfo($fname, $lname) {


$query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `registrants_info` (`first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES (?,?)");

$query->bindValue(1, $fname);
$query->bindValue(2, $lname);


try {

    $row = $query->execute();
    $insertId = $query->lastInsertId(); // <!-- Use this instead of a second query     

    #mail function can be added here

    }catch(PDOException $e) {

    die($e->getMessage());

}
```

}

Its also important to note that you are not inserting the 'email address' into your database, so there is no way for the query to find it by that field if you were to use another SELECT statement. You might want to complete your INSERT statement.